# Find targets in aerial images

Tags: opencv, detection, target

I'm trying to detect a specific target in some aerial images.
I tried **OpenCV Haar Cascades**. I get some results, but I'm not able to train a   reliable and consistent classifier.

I followed this tutorial

http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

and tried different methods to get the positive samples:

- cutting the samples from images like described in the tutorial
- creating different samples with photoshop and apply rotations and shear to them

I also tried **OpenCV template matching** with similar results.

Are there other ways to do what I want? I'm quite new in the field of objects detection.

Here are the target I want to detect and a sample image where they appear:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found one! I found one! 6m left of the boat. Do I get a prize? ;-)

Comment: Great, so basically I just need a simple script that sends the images to you, so you can do the detection and send me back the results :-D

Comment: Agreed! So all that's left to discuss is my fee... ;-)

Comment: Do you have control over the targets? The yellow is pretty easy to find, but the black is not helping you much since it occurs a lot naturally. How about 4 different colours that don't tend to occur in nature much? Magenta? Cyan - not much use if there's sky but you don't seem to be shooting obliquely.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a try HOG+SVM.
I think this method can solve your problem.

Here is an example: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d77/train_HOG_8cpp-example.html#a67